# hello everyone,when a class has a vector as it's data member,why its size is always 24?

Tags: c++, class, vector

here is the class

```
class A{
public:
    vector<int> vvv1{1};
};

class B{
public:
    vector<int> vvv2{1,2,3,4,5};
};
```

and the main

```
int main(){
    A a;/*sizeof(a) == 24;*/
    B b;/*sizeof(b) == 24;*/
    return 0;
}
```

why the size of a and the size of b are both 24?

Comment: `sizeof(std::vector)` is *not* the same thing as `std::vector::size()`/`std::size(std::vector)`. The first gives you the amount of bytes occupied by the type. The other two give you the number of contained objects/elements. Additionally `std::vector::capacity()` can tell you how many elements it can currently store before reallocation/growth is needed.

Comment: Remember `sizeof()` is a compile time constant. It only measures the size of the object not the size of any memory that the object dynamically allocates.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm thinking what the difference between  vector<int> vec and new vector<int> since vector is dynamically allocated.

Comment: `new vector<int>` creates a dynamically allocated vector. The difference would be the object itself would be dynamically allocated so in your case all 24 bytes would be on the free store as well. Note: It does not make a lot of sense to use this in most cases.

Comment: you are so nice for answer my questions.So that mines when I use new vector<int>, I just allocate 24Bytes from the heap, the contents of the vector are always dynamic allocated. What's more,when I use vector<int> *v = new vector<int>, v = 0x71dcf0. When I use vector<int> vec, &vec[0] = 0x7fd2e10a4010,what's the difference between two address.My computer is 64 bit.

Comment: ***I just allocate 24Bytes from the heap*** this part is not correct. You allocate 24 bytes on the free store + the amount the vector allocates to store your items.

Comment: ***what's the difference between two address*** Addresses don't have to be in the same range. This is a function of your OS + heap implementation + the amount of fragmentation of your heap.

Comment: thanks a lot for you nicely answer.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof()` gives you the number of bytes in memory that the object is occupying. The class `std::vector` is a container that has its own member variables to manage the internal array that it is representing, and they are counted as well as part of the size. Both `a` and `b` in your case are too small in number of elements to make it reallocate its internal array to hold more than what it initially uses to hold a single element.

For illustration, my compiler returns 32 for both these cases:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{ 1 };
    std::vector<int> b{ 1,2,3,4,5 };

    int sizeA = sizeof(a); // Returns 32
    int sizeB = sizeof(b); // Returns 32

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the contents of the vector does not change the size of the class. A vector object will always take up 24 bytes with the std lib implementation that you’re currently using. To be a dynamic array, the vector allocates memory on the fly to hold its contents. What’s actually in the vector class is the capacity of the vector, it’s current size, and a pointer to the data. Class sizes are always static

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm thinking what the difference between  vector<int> vec and new vector<int> since vector is dynamically allocated.

Comment: The vector class itself is not dynamically allocated. The vector uses dynamic allocation to store its data. Using `new vector<int>` will alllocate from the heap and require you to `delete` it later. Otherwise, they'll function the exact same since they are the same class. You just allocated the memory used for the class differently.

Comment: So that mines when I use new vector<int>, I just allocate 24Bytes from the heap, the contents of the vector are always dynamic allocated. When I use vector<int> *v = new vector<int>, v = 0x71dcf0. When I use vector<int> vec, &vec[0] = 0x7fd2e10a4010,what's the difference between two address.My computer is 64 bit.

Comment: I think you're confused as to what I meant by contents. I don't mean the member variables. I mean the array is dynamically allocated to allow for a dynamic array. `vector<int>` calls `new int[whateverSizeItNeeds]` when it needs store `int`s. The vector itself (i. e. the capacity, size, and pointer to the array) is not dynamically allocated unless you explicitly do so with `new`

Comment: thank you, I think I get your point now.